# Calling chart.update() with navigator options let the diagram shrink

Tags: highcharts

For my current project, I need to fetch data from the server and update the chart with a seperate navigator series data. When I do this, the diagram itself is shrinking, each time I call

```
chart.update({
    navigator: {
        //actually it doesn't matter what is written here
    }
});
```

It looks like it shrinks exactly as much space as would needed for another navigator.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pef8qLnb/13/)

Comment: There is no update method on the navigator object, and it's just causing the navigator to disappear. https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart

Answer (score 2):

It's already fixed on a `master` branch of Highcharts repository. In order to use the newest version of library please change links from:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

You can use those links until the new release comes out (what should happen this week), but we **don't** recommend using GitHub version on production enviroment.

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pavnLexd/

Comment: Hey, thanks, that sounds good. Can you tell me which version number this new release with the fix will have?